# UIDatePicker crashes with NSInternalInconsistencyException even when max date is nil

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I am using UIDatePicker in my app, which works perfectly in usual scenarios, but in there are situations, the same crashes the app with NSInternalInconsistencyException and the message is "Failed to allocate data stores for 100000 rows in section 0. Consider using fewer rows"

I know many of them have asked this question, but no where  proper solution is given

Please help me in this

Comment: Please post some relevant code

Comment: UIDatePicker *tempDatePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    tempDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;